# Why don't vectors need to be manually freed?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm just learning c++, coming from an understanding of both C and Java. I'm not quite understanding why some code that I wrote doesn't leak memory. Here's the code:

```
// Foo.h
class Foo {
private:
  std::vector<int> v;
public:
  Foo();
  virtual ~Foo();
  void add_int(int);
}

// Foo.cpp
Foo::Foo(): v () {}
Foo::~Foo() {}

Foo::add_int(int x) {
  v.append(x);
}
```

The vector stored in `v` obviously internally stores a pointer to heap-allocated memory, which needs to be freed, but I never free it. Valgrind, however, says that using this code doesn't leak at all. I feel that understanding why would help improve my understanding of the language.

Comment: Whether or not the code leaks depends on *how* you use it.

Comment: No `new` == no `delete`.  It's just that simple.  The vector deallocates memory via its destructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The secret is C++'s destructors. You wrote one that "does nothing" (`~Foo`), but in C++, member variables are automatically destructed when the class is destroyed.

`vector`'s destructor simply destroys every contained element, then deallocates its internal array.

Comment: It will also call the destructors for any elements in the internal array.

Comment: Interesting, so if I have a pointer to the same object in two different vectors, then freed one of them, the other one would be broken? What if the vector contains `int`s or something else that doesn't have a destructor method (or any methods at all). Are you sure that the vector's destructor calls the destructor of everything in the vector?

Comment: Destroying a plain pointer doesn't destroy what it points to. *That* would result in a memory leak if you freed a vector of pointers without freeing what the pointers pointed to. You are **strongly** recommended to use a smart pointer like `shared_ptr`, which will correctly destroy the object it points to once all the pointers are deleted.

Comment: @adrusi: Also, primitives and PODs (`int`, `char`, `x*`, etc.) don't have destructors. They are destroyed simply by deallocating the space they occupy.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't dynamically allocate `v` with `new`, so there is no need to `delete` it.

C++ guarantees member variables are automatically destructed when the Foo instance is destructed, and the vector sorts out its own affairs.

Answer (score 1):

The vector class's destructor will free the memory when the vector object is destroyed (and the vector object itself will be destroyed when your Foo object is destroyed)

Answer (score 0):

Because you allocated the vector on the stack, when foo goes out of scope all it's stack variables will have their destructors called automatically. When a destructor is called on a vector it will call the destructors of all the elements in it.

Had you allocated the vector on the heap you would have had to manually call  a delete on it or better still you could use a smart pointers to handle that for you automatically.